# Why is my simple recursive method's final return value always off by 1?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm attempting to create a text-based version of [this game](https://web.archive.org/web/20070106013537/http://www.cse.nd.edu/java/SameGame.html).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

class Clickomania {
    public:
        Clickomania();
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > board;
        int move(int, int);
        bool isSolved();
        void print();
        void pushDown();
        bool isValid();
};

Clickomania::Clickomania()
    : board(12, std::vector<int>(8,0)) {

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int color = (rand() % 3) + 1;
            board[i][j] = color;
        }
    }
}

void Clickomania::pushDown() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            if (board[j][i] == 0) {
                for(int k = j; k > 0; k--) {
                    board[k][i] = board[k-1][i];
                }
                board[0][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int Clickomania::move(int row, int col) {
    bool match = false;
    int totalMatches = 0;
    if (row > 12 || row < 0 || col > 8 || col < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int currentColor = board[row][col];
    board[row][col] = 0;

    if ((row + 1) < 12) {
        if (board[row+1][col] == currentColor)
        {
            match = true;
            totalMatches++;
            totalMatches +=  move(row+1, col);
        }
    }

    if ((row - 1) >= 0) {
        if (board[row-1][col] == currentColor) {
            match = true;
            totalMatches++;
            totalMatches += move(row-1, col);
        }
    }

    if ((col + 1) < 8) {
        if (board[row][col+1] == currentColor) {
            match = true;
            totalMatches++;
            totalMatches += move(row, col+1);
        }
    }

    if ((col - 1) >= 0) {
        if (board[row][col-1] == currentColor) {
            match = true;
            totalMatches++;
            totalMatches += move(row, col-1);
        }
    }

    return totalMatches;
}

void Clickomania::print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            std::cout << board[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    Clickomania game;
    game.print();
    int row;
    int col;
    std::cout << "Enter row: ";
    std::cin >> row;
    std::cout << "Enter col: ";
    std::cin >> col;
    int numDestroyed = game.move(row,col);
    game.print();
    std::cout << "Destroyed: " << numDestroyed << "\n";
}
```

The method that is giving me trouble is my "move" method. This method, given a pair of coordinates, should delete all the squares at that coordinate with the same number and likewise with all the squares with the same number connected to it.

If you play the link I gave above you'll see how the deletion works on a click.

```
int Clickomania::move(int row, int col) {
        bool match = false;
        int totalMatches = 0;

        if (row > 12 || row < 0 || col > 8 || col < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int currentColor = board[row][col];
        board[row][col] = 0;

        if ((row + 1) < 12) {
            if (board[row+1][col] == currentColor) {
                match = true;
                totalMatches++;
                totalMatches +=  move(row+1, col);
            }
        }

        if ((row - 1) >= 0) {
            if (board[row-1][col] == currentColor) {
                match = true;
                totalMatches++;
                totalMatches += move(row-1, col);
            }
        }

        if ((col + 1) < 8) {
            if (board[row][col+1] == currentColor)
            {
                match = true;
                totalMatches++;
                totalMatches += move(row, col+1);
            }
        }

        if ((col - 1) >= 0) {
            if (board[row][col-1] == currentColor) {
                match = true;
                totalMatches++;
                totalMatches += move(row, col-1);
            }
        }

        return totalMatches;
    }
```

My move() method above works fine, as in it will delete the appropriate "blocks" and replace them with zeros, however the number of destroyed (value returned) is always one off (too small). I believe this is because the first call of move() isn't being counted, but I don't know how to differentiate between the first call or subsequent calls in that recursive method.

How can I modify my move() method so it returns the correct number of destroyed blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're incrementing totalMoves in the wrong place(s).  You should count the match at the point where you set `board[r][c] = 0` and remove the other references to `totalMoves++`.

You are right that the first call isn't being counted, it's only counting the recursive calls.

Comment: @Stephen, this was it.  Thank you very  much!  I have one more quick question, how would I modify move() so that you couldn't move a square with no other matches adjacent to it?  In that, you couldn't flip a square and have it return 1 while only setting itself to "0".  It must at least have one match adjacent to it otherwise it will return 0 from the start and not set any square to 0.

Comment: You could provide a "hasAdjacentMatches" function, which you guard any actions with.  By the way, I like the Old School reference.

Answer (score 0):

0 based indexing.   You dont want to check >  you want >=

you wanna check  row >= 12    col >= 8

Comment: Where exactly are you talking about?  In the guard clause in the beginning?  My method is marking the correct squares as "0".  Only the count is off.

Comment: I think you are correct technically about those bounds, but that isn't what is making this method off by 1 in its return value.